# Java, user entered file location loop

Tags: java, file, while-loop

So I'm a first time programmer and I'm having problem with my loop and for the life of me I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. The code below is supposed to take the user entered location of the text file and if its correct it should there will be no error message but if its incorrect the error message "Incorrect file location" should pop and the user can input the correct location. But what happens is the error message pops up keeps popping up until I terminate the program. Can anyone give me some advice with what I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class ReadingText {

public static void main(String [] args ){
    System.out.println("Input the full path to the text file location: ");

    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String  userFileLocation = keyboardInput.nextLine();
    File s = new File(userFileLocation);
    boolean flag = false;

    while(flag = true)
    {

    try
    {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (s);
    while(sc.hasNext())
    {

    }
    }catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) 
    {
    System.out.println("Incorrect File Location");
    }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hint: `==` for comparison

Comment: Or simply `while(flag)`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems here.

First, you wrote `while(flag = true)`, which means "assign the value true to flag, and then continue looping if the resulting value of flag is true".  Such a loop won't exit (unless you call `break` from within the loop).

You probably meant `while(flag == true)` (note the use of two equal signs), which says "check if the value of flag is true, and continue looping if it is".  You could just as well say `while(flag)`.

The second problem is that you prompt the user for input before entering the while loop, so each loop iteration just looks at the same input that was given the very first time.  To fix this, move the code that prompts for (and reads) the user's input.  Instead of before the loop, it should be at the top of the loop.  That is, instead of

```
// prompt for input
// read input
while (flag == true) {
    // ....
}
```

you should have

```
while (flag == true) {
    // prompt for input
    // read input
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback and the help, Mark Adlesberger your answer solved my problem. I also appreciate the feedback on improving my style.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is this line:

```
while(flag = true)
```

`=` is assignment, not comparison. You want to use `==` for comparison.

Also, it's not necessary (and considered poor style) to explicitly compare to `true` and `false`, so in this case, you don't even need to do an explicit comparison at all. You can just do something like the following:

```
while (flag)
```

Also, you never actually set the value of `flag` inside the loop, so this is an infinite loop. You might consider something like the following:

```
catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) 
{
    System.out.println("Incorrect File Location");
    flag = false; // Break out of the loop at this point if that's what you intended
}
```

The effect of this will be to continue to prompt the user for file locations until they enter an incorrect file location (in which case it exits). You could also do the opposite (keep prompting them for a file until they enter a correct one).

You might also want to consider including a "special" keyword (like "Exit") and check for that to break out of the loop.

Finally, you explicitly set `flag` to `false` right before the loop, so there's no way for it to ever be `true`:

```
boolean flag = false;
```

The only reason it was working before was you were assigning `true` to it before instead of doing a comparison.

Answer (score -1):

While loop will end when flag is false. So write your code as below:

```
boolean flag = true;

while(flag) {

  if file found then 
  flag = false; // to exit while loop

  if file not found then keep flag = true so it will loop again...
```

Comment: This assumes, of course, that he wants to break out of the loop if the user enters a correct file. It would probably be better to have some kind of "reserved word" like "Exit" and check for that.

Comment: That is why I added the comment

Comment: flag = false; // to exit while loop

Comment: which is what you have done in your answer as well: flag = false; // Break out of the loop at this point if that's what you intended